# Mysql query max function for each row of a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max, window-functions

I want to create a new column with the max value of another column in each row but when I use `MAX()` function it return only one row.

I would like to have the same value in each row. From the first code without `MAX` function i get 533 rows, then when i use `MAX()` I only get one row.

```
SELECT
    ap.id,
    ap.name,
    apc.closing_prob_c
FROM a_assigned_prospect ap
LEFT JOIN a_assigned_prospect_cstm apc ON apc.id_c=ap.id
```

```
SELECT
    ap.id,
    ap.name,
    apc.closing_prob_c,
    MAX(apc.closing_prob_c)
FROM a_assigned_prospect ap
LEFT JOIN a_assigned_prospect_cstm apc ON apc.id_c=ap.id
```

Comment: So you want the new column to have the max value of `apc.closing_prob_c` over *the whole table*, while still returning 533 rows?

Comment: yes, i would like that

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the new column to have the max value of `apc.closing_prob_c` over *the whole resultset*, while still returning the original 533 rows.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, that's straight forward with a window max:

```
select
    ap.id,
    ap.name,
    apc.closing_prob_c,
    max(apc.closing_prob_c) over() max_closing_prob_c
from a_assigned_prospect ap
left join a_assigned_prospect_cstm apc on apc.id_c = ap.id
```

In earlier versions, you would typically use a subquery:

```
select
    ap.id,
    ap.name,
    apc.closing_prob_c,
    (
        select max(apc1.closing_prob_c) 
        from a_assigned_prospect_cstm apc1
        where exists (
            select 1 from a_assigned_prospect ap1 where ap1.id = apc1.id_c
        )
    ) max_closing_prob_c
from a_assigned_prospect ap
left join a_assigned_prospect_cstm apc on apc.id_c=ap.id
```